# How to run this in python

Tags: python

at this web address is some code. I would like to know how to run it in python. https://matt.ucc.asn.au/src/pbkdf2.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python   

# A simple implementation of pbkdf2 using stock python modules. See RFC2898
# for details. Basically, it derives a key from a password and salt.

# (c) 2004 Matt Johnston <matt @ ucc asn au>
# This code may be freely used, distributed, relicensed, and modified for any
# purpose.

# Revision history
# v0.1  October 2004    - Initial release
# v0.2  8 March 2007    - Make usable with hashlib in Python 2.5 and use
# v0.3  ""                 the correct digest_size rather than always 20
# v0.4  13 March 2009   - Mention distribution and relicensing in the copyright

import sys
import hmac
from binascii import hexlify, unhexlify
from struct import pack
try:
    # only in python 2.5
    import hashlib
    sha = hashlib.sha1
    md5 = hashlib.md5
    sha256 = hashlib.sha256
except ImportError:
    # fallback
    import sha
    import md5

# this is what you want to call.
def pbkdf2( password, salt, itercount, keylen, hashfn = sha ):
    try:
        # depending whether the hashfn is from hashlib or sha/md5
        digest_size = hashfn().digest_size
    except TypeError:
        digest_size = hashfn.digest_size
    # l - number of output blocks to produce
    l = keylen / digest_size
    if keylen % digest_size != 0:
        l += 1

    h = hmac.new( password, None, hashfn )

    T = ""
    for i in range(1, l+1):
        T += pbkdf2_F( h, salt, itercount, i )

    return T[0: keylen]

def xorstr( a, b ):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        raise "xorstr(): lengths differ"

    ret = ''
    for i in range(len(a)):
        ret += chr(ord(a[i]) ^ ord(b[i]))

    return ret

def prf( h, data ):
    hm = h.copy()
    hm.update( data )
    return hm.digest()

# Helper as per the spec. h is a hmac which has been created seeded with the
# password, it will be copy()ed and not modified.
def pbkdf2_F( h, salt, itercount, blocknum ):
    U = prf( h, salt + pack('>i',blocknum ) )
    T = U

    for i in range(2, itercount+1):
        U = prf( h, U )
        T = xorstr( T, U )

    return T


def test():
    # test vector from rfc3211
    password = 'password'
    salt = unhexlify( '1234567878563412' )
    password = 'All n-entities must communicate with other n-entities via n-1 entiteeheehees'
    itercount = 500
    keylen = 16
    ret = pbkdf2( password, salt, itercount, keylen )
    hexret = ' '.join(map(lambda c: '%02x' % ord(c), ret)).upper()
    print "key:      %s" % hexret
    print "expected: 6A 89 70 BF 68 C9 2C AE A8 4A 8D F2 85 10 85 86"

    # from botan
    password = unhexlify('6561696D72627A70636F706275736171746B6D77')
    expect = 'C9A0B2622F13916036E29E7462E206E8BA5B50CE9212752EB8EA2A4AA7B40A4CC1BF'
    salt = unhexlify('45248F9D0CEBCB86A18243E76C972A1F3B36772A')
    keylen = 34
    itercount = 100
    ret = pbkdf2( password, salt, itercount, keylen )
    hexret = hexlify(ret).upper()
    print "key:      %s" % hexret
    print "expected: %s" % expect



if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Summary of the problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20250731/getting-to-plain-text-from-hex-hash-xor-osx-sha512

I would like to know how to fish as well as getting this fish.

Comment: "I would like to know how to run it in python." -- as in, "How can I learn to write code like this?" or "Can you explain this code, please?" or "I want to execute this on my computer but I don't know how, please help."?

Comment: I should have wrote more clearly. I would like to know how to execute this script in python. I can do a little in terminal, but have not tried python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the termial try executing [1][2]:

```
python pbkdf2.py
```

[1] this assumes of course that you have named your file as the original owner did; `pbkdf2.py`.

[2] make sure you're in the directory of your file before running.

Comment: I suspect that's not exactly what OP's getting at.  But as the question stands, this answer looks to be it.

Comment: @BrianCain yeah I know what you mean, it just seems like its the only way to answer without reading his mind.

Comment: And make sure you have the python interpreter installed, and listed in the environment variables :)

Comment: so I save all of the script in a text file, open terminal, "cd" to that folder and then enter python "name_of_text_file_with Script"? sounds too easy

Comment: Save it as a python file, with `.py` extension. Assuming you have python installed.

Comment: Thanks Boys, that was much easier than I thought.